# Resultset not returning output

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I am trying to run this code but there is no output. But when I run the SQL query from my terminal, it works. Please help.

```
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
    ResultSet rset1=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ShowTime FROM Movie M, screens s WHERE M.MovieID = s.MovieID AND M.MovieID= 01");

    while(rset1.next()){
        //String tite=(rset1.getTimestamp("title"));
        System.out.println(rset1.getString("Showtime"));
        //text_39.append((rset1.getString("Showtime"))+"\n"); 
        }
```

Comment: there is no data to return. check your sql by running it in a sql client such as sqlplus for oracle or toad.

Comment: Not sure on your Java issue but as a suggestion for SQL you should use `JOIN` instead of old syntax. `SELECT ShowTime
 FROM Movie M
 JOIN screens s
  ON M.MovieID = s.MovieID
 WHERE M.MovieID = 01`

Comment: if M.MovieID is an numeric data type, the 01 will get truncated to just 1 which will not compare correctly with a string data type of '01'  you may need to wrap your '01' in tics so it looks like `WHERE M.MovieID = s.MovieID AND M.MovieID= '01'`

Comment: Also, Showtime != ShowTime

Comment: Logically if the query returns results in query window but not in java code the problem is either A) not pointed to right DB having data you expect B) logic writing output is flawed ("ShowTime"!="Showtime") C) you're getting an error when passing in the SQL that you're not trapping for in Java. SO 1) Confirm you're connecting to the same database with the same permissions you have in your query window, 2) update ShowTime, 3) add some error handling to see if you have an error in the SQL driver, and if so report the error message.

Answer (score 0):

if M.MovieID is an numeric data type, the 01 will get truncated to just 1 which will not compare correctly with a string data type of '01'  you may need to wrap your '01' in tics so it looks like `WHERE M.MovieID = s.MovieID AND M.MovieID= '01'`

My thought here is that the Driver and DB engine are doing some implicit casting which is preventing a syntax error but causing you to get no results when run though the driver.

To better answer the question I would need to know what data type MovieID is in Movie table and screens table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `ResultSet.getString(String)` is not case insensitive. Changing the value to `System.out.println(rset1.getString("ShowTime"));` should solve your problem